# $P(n) \subset P(n+c)$ implies $c=0$

Tags: number-theory

This question came up when I was solving a number theoery problem.

> Denote by $P(k)$ the set of prime numbers dividing $k$. Let $c$ be an integer. If $P(n) \subset P(n+c)$ is satisfied for infinitely many positive integers $n$. Does it follow that $c=0?$ (We say for two sets that $X,Y$ that $X \subset Y$, if $x \in X \implies x \in Y$)

I've been thinking about it for some time, and it seems true to me. But I haven't made any progress and I don't know how to proceed. I've made some trivial progress: the set of primes dividing $n$ that satisfy the conditions of the problems (that is $P(n) \subset P(n+c)$) is bounded. So if we manage to bound the $p-$adic valuation of those $n$ we'd be done.

Comment: Try $c=2$.  What does $P(n) \subset P(n+2)$ mean in terms of $n$?  Can you find infinitely many $n$ that satisfies this criterion?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Oh yes you are right. Powers of two work. What about if we loosen the condition to $P(n)=P(n+c)$

Comment: $$P(n) \subset P(n+c)\iff P(n) \subset P(c)$$$$P(n+c) \subset P(n)\iff P(n+c) \subset P(c)$$

Comment: Then you can prime-factorize $c$ and arrive at the same conclusion. Note that you have to treat $c = 1$ separately, but that case is easy.

Comment: @K.Jiang I'm sorry, I cannot see your point